# How do you limit the result of geolocator.geocode() in geopy?

Tags: python, geolocation, geocoding, reverse-geocoding, geopy

How do you limit the result of  geolocator.geocode() to a certain country only in geopy Python?

Comment: Hi! welcome to SO! This is a valid topic but you should check out [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and provide an example of what you are trying to do. It will attract more attention.

Comment: You should make clear if you want to just filter the results or limit the query.

Answer (score 1):

That would depend on a particular geocoder you want to use.

For example with `geopy.geocoders.GoogleV3`, the `geocode` method accepts parameters `bounds` and `region` using which one can supply a particular area of interest. These parameters map directly to those exposed by the [Google API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro). However, as the Google documentation states:

> This parameter will only influence, not fully restrict, results from
>   the geocoder.

More details can be found in the [Region Biasing](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#RegionCodes) section.